# find the last business date for June and Dec of any given year in Python

Tags: python-3.x, calendar

I want to find the last business day for the month of June and Dec for 2019. my below code gives me the last business day for last month and the current month. Ideally i want a code which allows me to input a year and month and it will tell me the last business day for the month and year i input.

i want my output to be like this for June 2019 and Dec 2019

2906
3112

hope someone can help me here, thanks

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BMonthEnd
from datetime import date

d=date.today()

offset = BMonthEnd()

#Last day of current month
current_month = offset.rollforward(d)
print(current_month)

#Last day of previous month
last_month = offset.rollback(d)
print(last_month)
```

Comment: Are you expecting to exclude holidays or does "business date" just mean "week day"?

Comment: Business day means workday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will find the last weekday in a given month and format it as a string in the format given

```
import datetime

def last_weekday(year, month):
    # Add a month
    if month == 12:
        month = 1
        year += 1
    else:
        month += 1

    d = datetime.date(year, month, 1)

    # Subtract a day
    d -= datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    # Subtract more days if we have a weekend
    while d.weekday() >= 5:
        d -= datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    return '{:02d}{:02d}'.format(d.month, d.day)

# Examples:
last_weekday(2019, 6)  # -> '0628'
last_weekday(2019, 12) # -> '1231'
```

Comment: Hi Kyle - add a quick question on this, is there anyway to express this same output but using lambda instead? im new to lambda but read you can use it a single line code and the results of this code i would only need once. thanks

Comment: It would certainly be possible to write a lambda for this, but it would be a massive unreadable lambda. In general, you should use a lambda only when the function is very short.